# How to pass configuration object for google visualization column chart from java server?

Tags: java, javascript, google-visualization

I want to draw a column chart on a browser using Google visualization chart. I implemented `DataSourceServlet` to return the `DataTable` from the server side. However, I also need to custom format the `vAxis` ticks. And I want the custom format label comes from the server as well.

How can I pass the `vAxis.ticks` object from the server to the client? I cannot find any method to attach it to the return `DataTable` object.

Comment: You could write your servlet to return an object with `ticks` and `DataTable` properties, placing the axis ticks in one and the DataTable in the other, then reference the object properties on the client side to get the relevant information.

Comment: I am implementing the DataSourceServlet https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_javadocs/com/google/visualization/datasource/DataSourceServlet. This servlet only expose the generateDataTable which return a DataTable object. So i think it has to attach to the DataTable object somehow. Are you suggested that I implement a different type of Servlet? I want a servlet that support the query syntax directly from the client side. The query language is here https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Comment: If you want to implement the DataSourceServlet generically (so anyone can call and use with without knowing any specifics of your implementation), then my suggestion will not work.  You could hijack the DataTable properties (returned in the `"p"` property of the object) to add the ticks.  None of Google's visualizations check the DataTable properties for anything, so you aren't likely to have any collisions there.